# Update Data Ajax Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I can't update because it appears that this request has no response data available, but when I run it with print_r the data appears, and when I set the update data query builder, the error appears. please help me..

```
    var id = $('#id').val();
    var akses_lihat = $('#akses_lihat').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url('User_Akses/update_akses') ?>',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            id: id,
            akses_lihat: akses_lihat
        },
        success: function(data) {
            
        }
    });



public function update_akses($id, $akses_lihat) {
    return $this->db->where('id', $id)->update('data_users_akses', array('akses_lihat' => $akses_lihat));
}
```

the hope is that my task will be completed quickly and found a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Change the model function like below. Ajax expects to return `JSON`. But your model return `TRUE/FALSE`

```
public function update_akses($id, $akses_lihat) {
    $response["status"] = false;
    $updateStatus =  $this->db->where('id', $id)->update('data_users_akses', array('akses_lihat' => $akses_lihat));

    if($updateStatus){
        $response["status"] = true;
    }
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not sending a valid `json` response from your `controller`. For that:

```
public function update_akses($id, $akses_lihat) {
    $status = $this->db->where('id', $id)->update('data_users_akses', array('akses_lihat' => $akses_lihat));

    // send json response back to ajax request
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(array('status' => $status)));
}
```

See `output` class details [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one, let me know if the code still doesn't work

**PHP Script**

```
<?php

public function update_akses($id, $akses_lihat) {

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $save = $this->db->update('data_users_akses', ['akses_lihat' => $akses_lihat]);

    if($save){
        $r = ['success'=>true, 'msg'=>'Data updated successfully!'];
    }else{
        $r = ['success'=>false, 'msg'=>'Data update failed!'];
    }

    die(json_encode($r));
}
```

**JS Script**

```
var id = $('#id').val();
var akses_lihat = $('#akses_lihat').val();

$.ajax({
    url: "<?= base_url('User_Akses/update_akses') ?>",
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        id: id,
        akses_lihat: akses_lihat
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**Note**

*Semangat gan ngodingnya!*